# Multiple Event Handler for Form Control Via VS interface

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010

I have a list box and I want to associate it with two event handler, by the interface in VS 2010 only allows me to specify one as shown below
[image]

I guess it might not be a good practise to temper with the designer code, is there anyway to done the adding the eventhandler via Visual studio interface? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> is there anyway to done the adding the eventhandler via Visual studio interface

You can always add an event handler in the form's constructor, after the call to `InitializeComponent()`, ie:

```
public Form1()
{
     InitializeComponent();
     lstDataset.SelectedIndexChanged += this.SecondEventHandler;
}
```

That being said, this is likely not a good idea.  There isn't really a reason for the *same class* to subscribe to the same event on the same object more than once.  You can just put the code for "both handlers" in the same method.

Comment: Another question whose answer might be an useful addition to yours: can we use delegates here?

Comment: @goldenparrot This IS using delegates - `this.SecondEventHandler` in the above code is an implicitly created delegate which is being added to the event invocation list.